# WPF Sample Data with Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a solution with two projects. The first project contains the definition of the database model and the second has the forms. I wonder what is the best way to use DesignData in the second project with the model defined in the first project. How do I link?

Comment: What types are the projects - applications or class libraries?

Comment: Do both projects HAVE to be applications? If you can make one of them a class library, then it makes it a lot easier to link things together. You can then use popular interface systems such as MVVM as suggested by @OmegaMan. With both of them being applications, you need to look into inter-process communications, through WCF, named pipes or other technologies, none of which are as straightforward as linking a class library into an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into an [MVVM architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

1. Put the visible window 'forms'/pages into a View project (which only handles user interactions and GUI operations.)
2. Create a View Model project which process the business logic which consumes the database models.
3. Use the View Model class(es) to bind to items on the view for display of the data.

You get the benefits of MVVM architecture by splitting out and seperating the concerns of the Model, the view and the business logic (view model).